# is it possible to pass a multiple database tables as a input to stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, r

By using `input_data_1` parameter I'm able to pass only one database table as a input to stored procedure  and  I'm fitting the forecast model using `R` language.

I have to use more than one database table in my stored procedure, but I'm not able to do that.

I spent lot of time to solve this but I couldn't, furthermore I don't have enough knowledge on `SQL`.

Can anyone help me to solve this?